# Highcharts - how to set custom content in point tooltip (popup) on 3D scatter chart or how to customize point tooltip information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, tooltip

I am new to Highcharts.

in this demo:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/gray

when the mouse move on one point, it shows up a tootip (popup) with default format as below:

```
Reading
x:0
y:4
z:9
```

I want to change and customize the information content being displayed in the tooltip and want to customize so that it displays content as below:

```
Reading
longitude:0
latitude:4
depth:9
```

So, can anyone can help me on this issue of customizing the content of tooltip?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/kmA59/2/)**

You should use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) option for customizing the tooltip display.

code:

```
tooltip:{
       // pointFormat:'{point.x}{point.y}{point.z}'
        formatter:function(){
            console.log(this);
            return '<b>'+this.series.name+'</b><br><b>longitude:</b>'+this.x+'<br><b>latitude:</b>'+this.y+'<br><b>depth:</b>'+this.point.options.z;
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is no series name.

Comment: I have updated my answer and demo link. You can check it now !

Comment: You can also use a [pointFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat)